# Why cache Dao inside DatabaseHelper, if its cached in DaoManage

Tags: android, ormlite

According to ORMLite documentation, all created Dao objects are cached inside DaoManager. But in ORMLite [examples](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/DatabaseHelper.java), I've seen Dao classes are again cached inside DatabaseHelper class. Do we really need it? ex.

```
public Dao<SimpleData, Integer> getDao() throws SQLException {
    if (simpleDao == null) {
        simpleDao = getDao(SimpleData.class);
    }
    return simpleDao;
}
```

My plan is to obtain Dao object when ever I need it and not to cache it inside my code base(In DatabaseHelper class), just want to allow DaoManager to cache Dao.

This is what I'm planing to use

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
Dao<SimpleData, Integer> myDao = databaseHelper.get.getDao(SimpleData.class);
```

Any performance issue if I obtain dao like this, instead of caching it inside DatabaseHelper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any performance issue if I obtain dao like this, instead of caching it inside DatabaseHelper?

No this is certainly fine.  You are doing a `Hashmap.get(..)` call each time but that is a very small hit -- especially when compared to any DAO operations or IO.

I would recommend not doing one of these for every call to the DAO:

```
databaseHelper.getDao(SimpleData.class).create(...);
databaseHelper.getDao(SimpleData.class).update(...);
```

But if you want to just get it at the start of the method and then perform a couple of operations then this should perform fine.

Comment: Thanks @Gray I got the perfect answer. Thanks for creating the best ORM framework for android.